# SQL query - using SELECT to retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I am using MySQL

I have the following two tables among others (in a database called database_01):

(i) Cities table, which contains names of cities in different countries, along with data such as in which countries these cities are located

Cities (city_id, city_name, country_id, ….)

(ii) Countries table in which I have defined the all the countries in the world along with an id for each country. I believe country_id in the Countries table is a primary key and it is a foreign key in the Cities table. (i.e. in the Cities table, country_id is used to denote, the country of a city.)

Countries (country_id, country_name,…)

Here the table Countries is kind of a master table as it remains basically static as the list of countries does not change frequently. However, the table Cities is kind of a transaction table, as I always add names of cities to this table, whenever I come across a new city along with the name of the country where this city is found.

I want to produce a report containing the list of Cities along with the name of the Country in which each city is located. (I want to ensure that each city name appears only once in the report, as I may have mistakenly entered the same city twice into the database.)

Eg:-

```
Country     City
USA         New York
USA         Washington
USA         San Francisco
USA         Chicago
UK          London
UK          Glasgow
UK          Liverpool
Germany     Bonn
Germany     Munich
France      Paris
```

I ran the following SQL statement

```
USE database_01;
SELECT countries.country_name
     , DISTINCT cities.city_name
     , FROM cities
     , countries 
 WHERE cities_country_id = countries_country_id   
 ORDER 
    BY country_name;
```

I am really grateful if someone can very kindly help me.

Comment: Sorry, the table is not formatted in the above question. The typed countries and cities in two columns but only the headers of the columns are there. The content of the table has got jumbled. It is a table containing two columns: Country and City. In the first column the countires would appear and in the second column the cities would appear. again sorry about it.

Comment: At this point, 20 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful.

Comment: Note that there are approximately 9 cities called Washington in the US.

Comment: _"But I am not getting what I want."_ What are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below query

```
select Distinct countries.country_name ,  cities.city_name
from countries left outer join cities on countries.country_id=cities.country_id
order by country_name
```

Comment: Thanks this works except for one thing. I want to get distinct values in the city_name column - not in the country_name column as I may have entered the same city more than once mistakenly. The country table is a fairly static table. Its values are unique, at least as far as I believe. And I need the country_name column as the first column (and sorted by the country_name column too, which is already there.) I modified your code and said SELECT countries.country_name, DISTINCT cities.city_name FROM ... but it looks like that you cannot use the keyword DISTINCT after the first column name.

Comment: It will help me to solve the issue if you can share sample duplicate values for cities table. [full duplicate rowes]

Comment: My city table is like this: Its column names are city_id, city_name, population, population density, country_id. It has one row like this: 34, Paris, 2,241,346, 21,616, 11 It has another row like this 72, Paris, 2,241,122, 21,613, 11. Here 11 is the country_code for France and 34 and 72 are city_id for Paris but there are two city_ids for Paris as I have entered Paris twice in this table. But I want Paris to appear only once in the report I want to produce. I do not mid which row out of 34 or 72. Any row is good enough as the accuracy of the values in the other columns do not matter much.

Comment: If you select only 2 column 'country' and 'city' then my provided query will remove duplicate city which you want.  I use in my query 'DISTINCT'  and Without 'DISTINCT' you will found result like 2 row . one is  'France' , 'Paris'  another is same  'France' , 'Paris' . Thus i use 'DISTINCT' to keep only one row.    [Another thing is DISTINCT before country column is not mean only distinct country value . it will actually distinct full row country , city]

Answer (score -1):

note: the distinct is applied on rows but not on individual columns

> select distinct cities and Left join countries with cities order by country name

your query is absolutely right if your use left join countries with cities
the solution is as follows

```
  USE database_01;
  SELECT DISTINCT cities.city_name, countries.country_name,
  FROM countries
  LEFT JOIN cities
  WHERE countries.country_id = cities.country_id 
  ORDER BY country_name;
```

Comment: Syntax error. DISTINCT belongs to SELECT, i.e. the correct _syntax_ is `SELECT DISTINCT ...`